# Ruby Installation on Ubuntu is really messed up

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rubygems

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit on Lenovo G580 Intel i5 laptop.

I started to learn Ruby and RoR just a few hours ago.
And then during the tutorials, I checked for Ruby and RubyGems, they were installed.

Then I tried installing Rails, and it failed to build the native extensions. Then I updated RubyGems, it still didn't work.

Then I installed Ruby from source, the latest version. This messed up RubyGems.

Now:

My Ruby version as per the command `ruby -v` is:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

My RubyGems version as per the command `gem -v` is:

```
1.8.23
```

Also, when I run `gem -v`, I get some warning:

```
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

This happened after I installed from source. Note: I didn't uninstall the already installed ruby first.

Now this is causing me too many problems.

How can I remove **everything** associated with Ruby?

Also, RubyGems gave me an error on installing Rails, so I looked up on the internet and installed a few packages like `build-essential`, `libyaml-ruby` and `libzlib-ruby`. This still gave me an error.

So now I want to remove all Ruby stuff, reinstall Ruby and RubyGems, and install Rails 3.

How can I do that?

Comment: The `ruby` Debian packages are completely broken. Use RVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing RVM.

Not sure if this helps:

http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/install-rvm-ubuntu-1204-linux-for-ruby-193
http://mattslay.com/installing-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-rvm-support/

Last time I used Ubuntu (2007) - it was the same, OSX doesn't make it much easier, but RVM takes most of the issues away.

Comment: hey, thanks for answering. I tried the steps in the article above. Unfortunately, RubyGem still gives me the same errors. :(

Comment: +1 this, ruby on debian is completely broken and shouldn't be used by anyone (but debian zealots). So, just remove anything installed (don't know how), install rvm, install ruby in it, have fun.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and the comment, I finally got everything working, following this article, here: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/